# Единица измерения em HTML

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, гуглить пытался, не нашел (наверное руки не оттуда). Как сделать, чтобы, например, я задал, что em = 10 и какому-нибудь тексту задал font-size: 2em (то есть 20), а потом при адаптации просто менял значение em. Все понятно, кроме того, где и как задавать чему равен em? Заранее спасибо

Comment: 1em - ширина буквы M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй не `em`, а `rem` и задавай его значение на `html`.

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

Comment: html{
rem=10;
} ?

Comment: Нет. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: значит у body fz=12?

Comment: Почитай уже что-нибудь...

Comment: Проверьте дебаты вокруг rem и em - https://zellwk.com/blog/rem-vs-em/  ++ https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/